# Problem with one-time developer registration fee

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I created chrome extension, uploaded into my new google developer account and tried to pay for one-time developer registration fee, but when I click into 'Pay now (5USD)' button and then into Buy button in 'Complete your purchase' modal window, then nothing happens. I tried to do it many times (also from firefox ;). Console shows: GET https://224.32.32.161/13161 net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID.

screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObLiV.png

I tried to contact with google, but with no success.. :/

Comment: Almost one month later, the problem still occurs. I contacted with few google support team, and every answer is like: contact with another google support team..

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your issue in a vanilla Chrome.
I would suggest to inform them about this issue here:
https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support

Comment: Thanks for updating.
Could you please try now?
If it doesn't work, I will raid them on Twitter. :D

Comment: I wrote to them by myself one month ago and now it's working ;)